# Divide function

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation

I need to write the divide function in the Jack language.

my code is:

```
function int divide(int x, int y) {

    var int result;
    var boolean neg;

    let neg = false;
    if(((x>0) & (y<0)) | ((x<0) & (y>0))){
        let neg = true;
        let x = Math.abs(x);
        let y = Math.abs(y);
    }

    if (y>x){
        return 0;
    }

    let result = Math.divide(x, y+y);

     if ((x-(2*result*y)) < y) {

        if (neg){
            return -(result + result);
        } else {
            return (result + result);
        }
    } else {
        if (neg){
            return -(result + result + 1);
        } else {
            return (result + result + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

this algorithm is sub-optimal since each multiplication operation also requires O(n) addition and subtraction operations.

Can I compute the product 2*result*y without any multiplication?

Thanks

Comment: @harold perhaps you can help?

Comment: I see I have been summoned. You could try restoring division, there's no multiplication in it.

Comment: @harold I'm not sure I understand...

Comment: can you detail your answer please

Comment: I could. Some other algorithm may be simpler actually. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of (unsigned) restoring division (`x/y`), I don't actually know Jack though so I'm not 100% sure about this

```
var int r;
let r = 0;
var int i;
let i = 0;
while (i < 16)
{
    let r = r + r;
    if ((x & 0x8000) = 0x8000) {
        let r = r + 1;
    }
    if ((y ^ 0x8000) > (r ^ 0x8000)) {  // this is an unsigned comparison
        let x = x + x;
    }
    else {
        let r = r - y;
        let x = x + x + 1;
    }
    let i = i + 1;
}
return x;
```

You should be able to turn that into signed division.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer but I can't use **0x8000** what is it?

Comment: @user3460154 the upper bit. You can probably write it as -32768

Comment: and for the operator **^** what I can used?

Comment: You can use + in this case (xor is like addition without any carries, since only the top bit is affected in this case, no carries are relevant)